# express http: 500 error on graphql mutation to create user from apollo client in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, graphql, apollo

trying to add a user using a graphql mutation in apollo but my server is giving me: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Response not successful: Received status code 500` not sure if I need to specify the server to use a post route or not? I thought if you just told express to use graphql at the certain route i.e /graphql it would read the mutation requests as needed

not sure why my server is sending me a 500 error though. As a side note I am able to fetch users from my server with no issues using apollo in my react app

hoping someone can tell me what's up with my express app that could be causing my issue, I've tried adding a post route as you'll see in the example but I still get a 500 error back

Apollo mutation in react

```
import {gql} from '@apollo/client';

export const CREATE_CUSTOMER_MUTATION = gql`
mutation addCustomer($id: Int! $name: String! $email: String! $age: Int!){
    addCustomer
    (id: $id name: $name email: $email age: $age)
          {
            id
            name
            email
            age
    }
}

`
```

Form in react to add user

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { CREATE_CUSTOMER_MUTATION } from '../GraphQL/Mutations'
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';

export default function Form() {
    const [id,setId] = useState("");
    const [name,setName] = useState("");
    const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const [age,setAge] = useState("");

    const [addCustomer, {error}] = useMutation(CREATE_CUSTOMER_MUTATION)
    const newCustomer = () =>{
        addCustomer({
            variables: {
                id: id,
                name: name,
                email: email,
                age: age
            }
        })
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text"
             placeholder="id"
             onChange = {(e) =>{
             setId(e.target.value)}}/>

            <input type="text"
             placeholder="name"
             onChange = {(e) =>{
             setName(e.target.value)}}/>

            <input type="text" 
            placeholder="email"
            onChange = {(e) =>{
            setEmail(e.target.value)}}/>

            <input type="text" 
            placeholder="age"
            onChange = {(e) =>{
            setAge(e.target.value)}}/>
            <button onClick={addCustomer}>Create Customer</button>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

EXPRESS SERVER

```
const express = require('express')
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP
const schema = require('./schema.js')
const cors = require('cors')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000


const app = express();
//allow CORS
app.use(cors())


app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
    schema:schema,
    graphiql:true,
}));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
  })


app.listen(port, ()=>{
 console.log(`server is running on port ${port}`)
});
```

my graphql schema on my express server

```
const axios = require('axios')
const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLNonNull
 } = require('graphql')


//hardcoded data

const customers =[
    {id: 1, name: 'luther wardle', email: 'lwardle@mail.com', age:35},
    {id: 2, name: 'steve smith', email: 'ssmith@mail.com', age:30},
    {id: 3, name: 'the main mayne', email: 'itme@mail.com', age:29},
    {id: 4, name: 'jojo mojo', email: 'jmojo@mail.com', age:14}   
]


//customer type
const CustomerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Customer',
    fields: () =>({
        id: {type:GraphQLString},
        name: {type:GraphQLString},
        email: {type:GraphQLString},
        age: {type: GraphQLInt}
    })
})

//Root Query
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields:{
        customer: {
            type:CustomerType,
            args:{
                id: {type:GraphQLString}
            },
            resolve(parentValue,args){
               
                for(let i =0; i<customers.length; i++){
                    if(customers[i].id == args.id){
                        return  customers[i]
                    }
                }
           
              
            }
        },

        customers:{
            type: new GraphQLList(CustomerType),
                resolve(parentValue,args){
                   
                    return customers
                }   
        }
    }
    
});
//mutation
const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'mutation',
    fields:{
        addCustomer:{
            type:CustomerType,
            args:{
                id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)},
                name: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                email: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                age: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)}
                
            },
            resolve(parentValue,args){
              
                // add to the list
              return customers
            }
        },
        deleteCustomer:{
            type:CustomerType,
            args:{
                id:{type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
            },
            resolve(parentValue,args){
                return axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/customers/'+args.id)
                .then(res => res.data);
            }
        },
        editCustomer:{
            type:CustomerType,
            args:{
                id:{type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                name:{type: GraphQLString},
                email:{type:GraphQLString},
                age:{type: GraphQLString}
            },
            resolve(parentValue,args){
                return axios.patch('http://localhost:3000/customers/'+args.id,args)
                .then(res => res.data);
            }
        }
    }
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery,
    mutation
});
```

Comment: Can you include anything in here about what error you're actually getting? Side note, you don't need the POST route. The app.use does that for you.

Comment: I've made some edits as I realized I hadn't specified the ID as a variable, but I'm using hardcoded data so nothing is handling the ID for me... I have also posted the error i'm getting and removed the post route, the only info I get back is that the response is bad ```Uncaught (in promise) Error: Response not successful: Received status code 500``` sorry if that's not super helpful XD I know the feeling

Comment: I will say that I have no issue getting all the customers back from the server only the mutations are causing this problem which leads me to believe my query is the issue but it looks fine to me

Comment: You have GraphiQL enabled. Can you make the query directly to the API and get a better Error stack?

Comment: thanks for the tip, after a little research I found that my form was passing all the variables as strings when ID and Age should have been Ints, after parsing the Ints the issue was resolved :)

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged. So that your question doesn't appear as unanswered

Answer (score 0):

my form was passing all the variables as strings when ID and Age should have been Ints, after parsing the Ints the issue was resolved

as shown below I've changed the variables inside my form component

```
    const newCustomer = () =>{
        addCustomer({
            variables: {
                id: parseInt(id),
                name: name,
                email: email,
                age: parseInt(age)
            }
        })
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```